# Hide button when ng-repeat get finished

Tags: angularjs

I want to hide the button when ng-repeat get finished. but here in my code I am not able to access the $index value.

can anybody give me hint?

```
  <div class="row">
                            <ul class="list-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                              <li class="list-group-item row border-bottom-gray" ng-repeat="trans in transaction.response.transactions|limitTo:count" >
                                <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8">
                                  <span class="text-muted">{{trans.txnDate}}</span>
                                  <span>{{trans.txnDescription}} 
                                  </span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 text-right">
                                  <strong>{{trans.credit}}</strong>
                                  <span class="text-muted">Credit</span>
                                </div>
                              </li>

                            </ul>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center"></div>
                            <div style="position: static" class="showMore col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4 col-md-offset-4 col-md-4">
                              <button style="position: static" class="btn btn-block btn-default center-block" ng-click="count = count + 9" ng-init="count=9" ng-hide="transaction.response.transactions.length == $index">
                                Show more
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                              </button>

                            </div>
                          </div>
```

Comment: You cannot access $index outside the ng-repeat

Comment: ya I got to know that... but somehow I need to hide the button..

Answer (score 0):

$index will not be available after the `</li>`

Comment: yes you are right.. but is there anyway how can I get the count of ng-repeat outside the </li>, so that I can hide button

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by custom directive :-

```
<li class="list-group-item row border-bottom-gray" ng-repeat="trans in transaction.response.transactions|limitTo:count" on-last-repeat >

angular.module('myapp', [])  
    .directive('onLastRepeat', function() {
        return function(scope, element, attrs) {
            if (scope.$last) setTimeout(function(){
             $("button_id").hide();  <- provide id of your button. 
            }, 1);
        };
    })
```

This is not the good answer but it will work for you.

Comment: Your code, as written, will hide the button immediately.  $last isn't set on the source array, it's set on the filtered array.

Answer (score 0):

You are overthinking it:

```
<button style="position: static" class="btn btn-block btn-default center-block" ng-click="count = count + 9" ng-init="count=9" ng-show="count < transaction.response.transactions.length">
    Show more
    <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

No need to use $index